# emacs on Windows + sql + ssh

Tags: sql, oracle, emacs, ssh

Our university runs an Oracle database server. We log in using campus username/password over SSH, then `rlwrap sqlplus` is automatically started and we have to log in again, to the database application, using another username and password.

I would like to use Emacs on Windows to edit and run simple SQL scripts on this server. I am already able to edit files on other SSH servers using Tramp, but for some reason (most likely the automatic launch of `sqlplus`) I'm not able to do that on the database server. Emacs hangs with `Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell`.

I would also like to run an interactive SQL session in a buffer, so I inserted the code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277015/1813487 to my `.emacs` with appropriate modifications (namely, change all occurrences of `mysql` to `oracle`). When I do `M-x sql-oracle`, Emacs hangs with `Tramp: Sending Password`.

Is there a way to fix/configure all this, or the only way is to convince the admin to disable the automatic launch of `sqlplus`?

---

It may or may not be important that I could only make Tramp work by re-compiling `tramp.el` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764972/1813487). I have little to no knowledge of Emacs Lisp.

Comment: Surely the way to do this is to talk to your system/network admins? P.S. You can call OS commands from SQL*Plus by using the HOST command; but there's no guarantees you're going to have the privileges to write a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to edit the `.bashrc` file on the server so that SQLPlus does not automatically start.

Answer (score 0):

Tramp-over-SSH works by starting an SSH session and then sending it shell commands.  So if your SSH sessions can't run a shell, you won't be able to use Tramp-over-SSH to access your remote files.

As for starting SQL from Emacs, the way to do that is to set `sql-oracle-program` to some script that performs the necessary commands, in your case probably something like `ssh <oracle-server>`.

Comment: The server does run a shell; I can access it by exiting the database username prompt with `Ctrl-D`.

Comment: @marczellm, if you can access the shell maybe you can edit the login script (.bash_profile if you are using bash) and remove the automatic launch of sql session.  If the login script is protected (/etc/profile), you could tell tramp to send a ^D when he receives the SQL prompt.

Comment: @juanleon Which variable to use for that, and do I literally type `^D`?